# Not able to connect/run a operation on android device in android studio

Tags: android, selenium, android-studio, automation, appium

I am not able to connect or runb a script on a real android device from android studio and geeting the following error:

[image]

The code is as follows:
    import org.junit.Before;

```
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Sample {

    private static RemoteWebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities  capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "Chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void testcase_001() throws Exception{
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        WebElement keyword = driver.findElementByName("q");
        keyword.sendKeys("appium");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnK")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

But the device is listed in Android device monitor

[image]

And shown connected in cmd

[image]

And the things that I tried is changing the following settings:

- Android studio > Run > Edit Configuration > In Gerenal tab > set Target as USB DEVICE.

Any Idea what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last apk if you already installed before and try to install new apk.

Comment: no effort tried that, even tried to put a new .apk there. same results

Comment: i think there is another app which is having the same files. It may be the issue.